# Android App not showing on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am having a serious issue where, when I run my app to the emulator, the app is not visible in the homescreen. The emulator works fine, builds fine, the project builds fine as well, it's just the app is nowhere to be found in the emulator.

I've tried running multiple AVD's, the SDK version is matched etc. I've tried checking and unchecking enable ADB integration. Nothing seems to work.

I've noticed that, on the android monitor, it says "no debuggable applications." Also, whilst the emulator running, on the logcat I've noticed some lines were red (hard to read cause it goes by so fast). For example: "07-02 01:11:23.714 0-1142/? E/cutils: Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory" and "07-02 01:11:24.725 1129-1129/? E/lowmemorykiller: Kernel does not support memory pressure events or in-kernel low memory killer"

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Quite idiotic, but I found the problem. Actually, it wasn't due to a problem at all. I realized I was "running" the emulator and thought that my app would appear on the homescreen by itself. I didn't know I had to go back to the IDE and click run, select the running device and run it again.